# print to network printer from python in Ubuntu Server 22.04.2

Tags: python, printing, ubuntu-server

I have a python script that downloads a PDF using selenium webdriver and i need it to print it to an epson l450 printer in my LAN. This will run in an Ubuntu server. how can i do it?

so far i was planning to do

```
if nfile!=logname:
            os.startfile(file, "print")
            time.sleep(5)
            for p in psutil.process_iter():
                if 'AcroRd' in str(p):
                    p.kill()
```

but this only works in Windows